# discord.js Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried making a command for my bot that is a little coinflip game. When I run the command it says "Maximum call stack size exceeded". Here's my code:

```
let optionChose = null;
    function flipACoin() {
      let options = ['heads', 'tails'];
      let option = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
      if (option === optionChose) {
        msg.reply('you won! :)');
      } else {
        msg.reply('you lost! :(')
      }
    }
    function ifs() {
      if(msg.content === 'heads') {
        optionChose = 'heads';
      } else if (msg.content === 'tails') {
        optionChose = 'tails';
      } else {
        msg.reply('you need to choose heads or tails!');
        ifs();
      } 
    }

    if (msg.content === '!coinflip') {
      msg.reply('heads or tails?');
      ifs();
      flipACoin();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you reply to the message but never wait for a response, which means that the message content will not be `heads` or `tails`, it'll be `!coinflip`. Also, `ifs` calls itself without waiting for another message, which leads to infinite recursion, causing the "call stack exceeded". Look into [`MessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector) and [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Comment: Your code is looping infinitely, which leads it to exceed the maximum call stack size.

Comment: Oh. So how could I fix it? Sorry if this seems pretty dumb, I'm not super experienced with programming.